# How to have a driver class inherit certain attributes of a super class?

Tags: java

I am trying to have my driver class inherit the information from two different classes. I have to use the formula className objectName = new className(input parameters) to instantiate one of the classes. But I keep getting the symbol not recognized error.

I'm not sure how I could fix this problem. I tried creating an import statement, but the other two classes are part of the same package. I have also tried using the extends keyword, but also noluck

```
public class Corgi extends Dog {

    // additional class variables
    private static int weight;
    private static int age; 

    // constructor
    public Corgi(String type, String breed, String name, int pounds, int years) {

        // invoke Dog class (super class) constructor
        super(type, breed, name);
        weight = pounds;
        age = years;
    }

    // mutator methods
    public static int setWeight(int pounds){
        weight = pounds;
        return pounds; 

    }

    public static int setAge(int years){
        age = years;
        return years;

    }

    // override toString() method to include additional dog information
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return (super.toString() + "\nThe Corgi is " + age +
                " years old and weighs " + weight + " pounds.");
    }

}
```

```
public class Dog {

    // class variables
    private static String type;
    private static String breed;
    private static String name;
    private static String topTrick;

    // constructor
    public Dog(){
        type = "none";
        breed = "none";
        name = "none";


    }

    // methods
    public static String setTopTrick(String trick){
        topTrick = trick;
        return trick; 


    }

    // method used to print Dog information
    public String toString() {
        String temp = "\nDOG DATA\n" + name + " is a " + breed +
                ", a " + type + " dog. \nThe top trick is : " +
                topTrick + ".";
        return temp;
    }

}
```

```
public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Corgi tricker = new Corgi();    

    tricker.setTopTrick("Backflip");    

    System.out.println(tricker);
    }
}
```

I am expecting to be able to have the main class inherit Corgi's info with the Corgi tricker = new Corgi(); statement. But I keep getting the error:

> Main.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
>       Corgi tricker = new Corgi("Hunting", "Shiba", "Simon", 30, 7);
>       ^
>     symbol:   class Corgi
>     location: class Main

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to match up. Corgi doesn't have a parameter-less constructor

Comment: A few problems here. 1) The line in your posted `main` doesn't match your error. 2) your constructor for `Dog()` doesn't match what you are calling in `super` for `Corgi`

Answer (score 1):

1. In your `Corgi class` you need to remove variables from `super()`

```
 public Corgi(String type, String breed, String name, int pounds, int years) {

        // invoke Dog class (super class) constructor
        super();
        weight = pounds;
        age = years;
    }
```

2.Then you have to add values in `Corgi();` which is in `Main class'

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
         Corgi tricker = new Corgi("puppy", "Husky", "Alex", 15, 1);    

            tricker.setTopTrick("Backflip");    

            System.out.println(tricker);

    }
```

**output -:**

```
DOG DATA
none is a none, a none dog. 
The top trick is : Backflip.
The Corgi is 1 years old and weighs 15 pounds.
```

Comment: Close, but not quite what OP wants. The correct answer would probably be to add type, breed and name to the constructor for `Dog()`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone. My code wasn't the problem. I tried using the code in a different compiler and it worked just fine. I did tweak my code a little with Kalana's advice. Thanks everyone.